# CakePHP redirect when user go to login page when already logged in

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I just want to ask how to redirect a user trying to access the login page even if he's logged in already. I don't have any code to show because I don't even know where to look.

Basically first you go to the login page which is `user\login` after logging in successfully you get redirected to `\profile` now if you type in the URL `user\login` the login form should not be shown and you should be redirected to the profile instead to avoid logging in twice. I hope you understand thank you very much!

Comment: Show us what you have tried, what's worked and specific issues you are having. That's the best way to get help here. (Right now your question sounds like you are just asking someone to write the code for you.)

Comment: If you're not sure where to start. Try implementing a simple login system first. You can start with the example and tutorial in the CakePHP book http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the below code where you don't want logged in users to view that page.

```
// check whether user is logged in
if($this->Auth->user()) {
 // redirect to other page
}
```